# Python googletrans

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

I just came across **googletrans** **python** package. This package **translates** quite well and seems to use **google** **translation** **API**. To my knowledge, google translation **API** is **not free**. What **googletrans** doing **internally** for the translations? Is it **legal** to use **googletrans**?

Comment: Read their documentation. It's free up to i think 500 translations a day and in non-profit situations. Prices: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing, doc: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation has information on this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googletrans#how-does-this-library-work

> You may wonder why this library works properly, whereas other approaches such like goslate won’t work since Google has updated its translation service recently with a ticket mechanism to prevent a lot of crawler programs.
>
> I eventually figure out a way to generate a ticket by reverse engineering on the obfuscated and minified code used by Google to generate such token, and implemented on the top of Python. However, this **could be blocked at any time**.

As for the legality of this approach, this kind of stuff depends on the laws of the countries you live in, and is probably slightly off-topic.